# Node.js with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-mssql, tedious

Has anyone had any success getting Node to communicate with a SQL Server database?

I've tried all the solutions posted on Stackoverflow (although all relevant questions seem to be about a year old) and none of them have worked.

Some of the packages I've tried:

- msnodesql (Unable to get it to install successfully),
- mssql, tedious (Always errors out on socket connection)

and some others that I can't remember their names

I think all the packages are out of date or not being maintained anymore, as far as I can see there is no defacto standard. I'm starting to think I should abandon trying to use a SQL Server database and switch to MySQL instead?

I'm developing in Visual Studio 2012 and I also have SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'm afraid I have. I hit multiple errors when trying to build it, it complains about something relating to Visual Studio 2010 (I have 2012). Currently installing something Visual Studio 2010 related as a long shot to getting it to build, but I doubt it will work. Seems to me it's just very out of date.

Answer (score 2):

I'am author of [node-mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) module and i would like to help you solve your problem. Could you please provide more information about the errors you get and config you're using?
I have made some changes in connection errors recently, so maybe you could try latest version 0.5.0.

Also you could try precompiled msnodesql drivers [here](https://github.com/jorgeazevedo/node-sqlserver-binary). I was also unable to install it on my machine via npm. If this will work for you, try using [node-mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) with msnodesql as an optional driver, it can save you a lot of lines of code and make you work with SQL Server more enjoyable.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you on this, I meant to then got side tracked then forgot. I decided to move away from MSSQL and node after not being able to get it working. But I will revisit it if you'd still like to work on a fix?

Comment: Yes, sure, Iam here to help.

Comment: I figured it out, in my config I must specify the port and not the instance name. Thanks for your help. e.g. `var config = {user:'****',password:'****',server:'localhost',database:'MyDatabase', options:{port:1433}}`

Answer (score 0):

this setting work in express.js 2022, sql server 2014

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {
user: 'your user',
password: 'your password',
server: 'your server', 
database: 'your database',
"options": {
          "encrypt": false,
          "enableArithAbort": true,
          "trustServerCertificate":false
          }
};


sql.connect(config, function (err) {

if (err) console.log(err);

// create Request object
var request = new sql.Request();

// query to the database and get the records
request.query('select * from a_pinfinger', function (err, recordset) {

    if (err) console.log(err)

    // send records as a response
    //res.send(recordset);
    console.log(recordset);
});
});
```